# gatsby"permission to view this setting." email

Tags: wordpress, gatsby, graphiql, wp-graphql

When working with Gatsby and the GraphiQL web console, I get the following error in the output from a query that accesses the site email:

> Sorry, you do not have permission to view this setting.

This was after updating to the latest version of WPGraphQL v1.9.0 (although it may have been in previous versions).

My setup:

- NON-PUBLIC WordPress - I just run it locally in a docker instance.
- Gatsby with `gatsby-source-wordpress` to load & generate my static site
- Netlify publish of the static site

So hence there is zero need for any actual auth to Wordpress.

Answer (score -2):

Turns out the easiest fix was to just toggle the icon in the GraphiQL web console to use the logged in user to run the query.

[image]